# Device Reboots on Hitting Breakpoint in GDB During Black Box Analysis of Multi-Threaded Embedded Server

Tags: c++, security, debugging, gdb, embedded-linux

I'm currently analyzing a black box device, specifically a multi-threaded server running in an embedded environment, using gdb for debugging. I've encountered a persistent issue: whenever I set a breakpoint in gdb and it's hit, the device reboots after a few seconds.

Details of my setup include:

1. I set a breakpoint in main binary's certain function.
2. When program hit the breakpoint.
3. A few seconds later, device reboots.

This rebooting behavior occurs during my black box analysis, and I suspect it might be related to the server's multi-threading or unique aspects of the embedded system. Has anyone faced similar issues or can offer insights into potential causes? Any troubleshooting advice or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just speculating: Maybe, there is some kind of safety code in the server which uses a timer to detect that the execution is stuck (endless loop, abort). If it's not reset after a certain time, an interrupt is fired which causes the reboot. Due to your debugging the timeout gets due. In such (time-critical) cases (or to debug GUI interaction itself), there is still print debugging which could be used. That might be possible even by using the debugger (without changing the code). I don't know how to achieve this in gdb but already used it in Visual Studio. Hence, gdb might provide it as well...

Comment: FYI: [A Guide to Watchdog Timers for Embedded Systems](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/firmware-watchdog-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a watch dog issue. When the breakpoint is hit, watchdog signals are not send anymore by your process and the system tries to restart this process. Since the binary is "already running/in use" it may conclude this is catastrophic and then decide to restart the system.

If your device is using systemd, look for the service file for your task and comment out `WatchdogSec=`. Also read about the [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html) watchdog while at it.

If the system is not using systemd, it may have a propritary implementation of a watchdog. If you can find the function name that initialises the watchdog (`nm` or `strings` on the binary and `grep`ing for `watchdog`) you can implement a dummy function in an .so and use `LD_PRELOAD=dummywd.so` to override it.